# curl exit status code issue while using authentication

Tags: bash, curl

I'm writing a script to check whether a file can be downloaded from a remote server using curl. The script will report if there is a problem downloading the file or the file is not present. I'm using the below code snippet:

```
curl --fail -u "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD" --remote-name "$HOST/$FILEPATH"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
echo "There is some error in Downloading file from $HOST";
else
echo "Download success";
fi
```

But I always get the exit status code as 0. That's because curl always downloads the file ( even when the file is not present) and you can find the actual error message in that file.

So how can I get the real curl exit status code ( 22 file not found) ?

Answer (score 3):

`--fail` will return an error code of `22` in case of http protocol and
the return code may be different for other protocols say ftp. See below :

```
me@udistro:~$ curl --fail ftp://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/brms/6.2.0/en/source/MD5 
curl: (78) RETR response: 550
me@udistro:~$ echo $?
78
```

But as the man page states :

> This  method is not fail-safe and there are occasions where
>   non-successful response codes will  slip  through,  especially  when
>   authentication is involved (response codes 401 and 407).

As a starting point you could try this :

```
curl --fail -u "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD" --remote-name "$HOST/$FILEPATH"
var=$?

if [ $var -ne 78 ] && [ $var -ne 22 ]
then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failed"
fi
```